# Understanding the step cannot be zero error in Julia Language?

Tags: julia

I need a vector of UnitRanges as follows:
[2:5, 3:6, 4:7, 5:8]

when I try to run this (2:5):(5:8), I get an error of "ArgumentError: step cannot be zero."

Is there a way of creating a UnitRange array using UnitRange itself?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to *map* or *broadcast* `:` over the elements in the two arguments.  Just do it explicitly:

```
julia> map(:, 2:5, 5:8)
4-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 2:5
 3:6
 4:7
 5:8
```

Now, ideally you'd also be able to write this as `(2:5) .: (5:8)` — you'd dot the `:` operator to broadcast it — but since `:` is used for so many things and since this isn't a very common use-case we've not enabled the dotting of `:`.  You can, however, use the non-infix form and dot that:

```
julia> (:).(2:5, 5:8)
4-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 2:5
 3:6
 4:7
 5:8
```

As for the error message you're getting, it's because the first thing `:` tries to do is determine the length, assuming its two arguments are scalars.  To do this it subtracts the first argument from the second:

```
julia> (5:8) - (2:5)
ERROR: ArgumentError: step cannot be zero
```

That fails because it's trying to create a step range that's effectively `3:0:3` and has a length of 4.

Comment: But I think the poster wants even more: not a `Vector{UnitRange}` but a `UnitRange{UnitRange}`...

Comment: Hi, I need UnitRange{UnitRange}. I will use that UnitRange array to broadcast rows from a matrix. I was trying to reduce the number of for loops by using this.

Comment: But why? Julia's `for` loops are fast and needn't be avoided.  And a `Vector{UnitRange}` will work just like your hypothetical `UnitRange{UnitRange}`.

Comment: Yes, but it will allocate a lot more. That's the purpose of ranges, right? A lightweight, lazy, clever type of array that uses virtually no memory.

Comment: A little bit, yes.  It will just store the endpoints of each range. Amazingly, this does work with `StepRangeLen`s, which can support that 0-step range.  `StepRangeLen(2:5, StepRangeLen(1,0,4), 5)`.